# How to find area of the color on screen

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, quartz-2d

Let’s say I have a paint application. Users draw with whatever colors they select and then they click a button that evaluates how much a each color takes up the screen. Is this something easy to do in the cocos2d or any API for the iPhone/iPad? If not, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand graphics bitmaps, you could just draw the screen context to an RGB (etc.) bitmap context.  Then, in the bitmap, count all the pixels that meet your criteria, and calculate the percentage, or whatever.